# Uploading multiple files stuck on error

Tags: php, file-upload

I have finally made some progress. Now when I upload 2 images it gets put into my array. I am attaching my vardumb. However the file does not actually upload? Any ideas?

```
array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "1bTUWI3.jpg"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "1T1NBmd.jpg"
  }
  ["type"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
  }
  ["tmp_name"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpgB2bAe"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpg8ZZk1"
  }
  ["error"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(0)
    [1]=>
    int(0)
  }
  ["size"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(671869)
    [1]=>
    int(352029)
  }
}
    function uploadFile()

} 
$files = array();
$fdata = $_FILES['userfile'];
if (is_array($fdata["name"])){
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($fdata['name']); ++$i) {
        $files[] = array(
        'name' => $fdata['name'][$i],
        'tmp_name' => $fdata['tmp_name'][$i],
        'size' => $fdata['size'][$i],
        'filetype' => $fdata['type'][$i],
        );
    }

    echo '<pre>';
var_dump($fdata);
echo '</pre>';
$username=$_SESSION['name'];
$alt=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['alt']);

$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["userfiles"]["name"]));
if((($fdata['type'] == "image/gif")
    ||($fdata['type']=="image/jpeg")
    ||($fdata['type']=="image/png")
    ||($fdata['type']=="image/pjpeg")
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)))
    {
        $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
        $content =fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
        $SourceImage = imagecreatefromstring($content);
        $SourceWidth = imagesx($SourceImage);
        $SourceHeight=imagesy($SourceImage);
        $DestWidth=100;
        $DestHeight=130;
        if ($SourceHeight> $SourceWidth)
        {$ratio = $DestHeight / $SourceHeight;
        $newHeight = $DestHeight;
        $newWidth = $sourceWidth * $ratio;
        }
        else
        {
            $ratio = $DestWidth / $SourceWidth;
            $newWidth = $DestWidth;
            $newHeight = $SourceHeight * $ratio;
        }
        $DestinationImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
        imagecopyresampled($DestinationImage, $SourceImage, 0,0,0,0,$DestWidth, $DestHeight, $SourceHeight, $SourceWidth);
        ob_start();
        imagejpeg($DestinationImage);
        $BinaryThumbnail = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $thumb = addslashes($BinaryThumbnail);
        $content = addslashes($content);
        fclose($fp);
        $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
        $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
        $content = addslashes($content);
        fclose($fp);

          mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO files (username, name, size, content, type, link, alt, thumbnail) VALUES ('$username', '$fileName', '$fileSize', '$content', '$fileType', 1, '$alt', '$thumb')") or die('Error, query failed'); 
           echo "<script>alert('The file has been uploaded');location.replace('uploaded.php');</script>";


    }else{ 
           echo "<script>alert('Please upload an image');location.replace('upload.php');</script>";
    }

}
}
```

I am still getting stuck at my echo error.

My form looks like this.

```
      <h1>Upload a file</h1>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="process.php">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
<label>Upload File:
<input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile"></label>
<br>
<label>Alt Text: <input name="alt" type="text"></label>
<input name="UploadFile" type="submit" />
</form>
```

My vardump looks like this

```
array(1) {
  ["userfile"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(17) "Desert - Copy.jpg"
    }
    ["type"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "image/jpeg"
    }
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(14) "/tmp/phpIpCoQ3"
    }
    ["error"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(0)
    }
    ["size"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(845941)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As far as I see `$file` will not exist after the first if/else construct. Additionally you need `{}` around the `foreach`.
But that's probably not all errors, so take it as comment.

Comment: How do I make the $file exist outside the if else?

Comment: The structure of $_FILES for a _multiple_ file upload is not what you think it is – so use var_dump to see what it _actually_ looks like!

Comment: And set your error_reporting to a value that sensible for developing – PHP would have told you that you are trying to access indexes that aren’t there if you had done that.

Comment: I thought that error meant that it wasn't the right file type.
I added the var dumb

Comment: So you see, you are not getting a numeric index on the first level, but you get keys `name`, `type`, etc., and _underneath those_ then numerically indexed data for each of the upload fields in the form. So trying to loop through this data with foreach doesn’t make much sense – a `for` loop and inside that accessing `$_FILES[specific key - name,type,etc.][loop-counter]` makes more sense.

Comment: Ok I finally have something going into my array but now I am unsure how to get each file by itself into the database

Answer (score 0):

**First** confirm that it is `userfile` not `username`

And Check `error` in `loop` like,

```
// check the userfile array is set and it is not empty
if(isset($_FILES["userfile"]) and !empty($_FILES["userfile"]))
{
    // loop for each file to upload
    foreach ($_FILES['userfile'] as $file)
    {
       // check for error and size
       if (($file["error"] == 0) && ($file['size'] > 0))
       {
          // your remaning code
```

And in **HTML** use the `array` of `file names` like,

```
<input type="file" name="userfile[]" />
<input type="file" name="userfile[]" />
```

Comment: Yes that is what I have in the form.

Comment: Please _show_ us what you did by editing your question with your current code!